# Prevent the double query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My goal is to pull data from sql database and split into two arrays (req of library) so that I can graph the data. The problem is that my process is creating two database queries instead of one.

In the controller:

```
def words_popular
    words = Word.select(:word, :popularity).order(popularity: :desc).limit(100)
    @words = words.pluck(:word)
    @popularity = words.pluck(:popularity)
  end
```

and the resulting log:

```
(1.9ms)  SELECT  `dictionary`.`word` FROM `dictionary`  ORDER BY `dictionary`.`popularity` DESC LIMIT 100
(2.0ms)  SELECT  `dictionary`.`popularity` FROM `dictionary`  ORDER BY `dictionary`.`popularity` DESC LIMIT 100
```

Is the problem the double plucking? Can I do the array split in one line?

Also, in future, is there a way to force the query? In Node mongoose, I would call exec() on the relation to cause it to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
words, popularity = Word.pluck(:word, :popularity).transpose
```

and than words contains an array of words and popularity an array of popularity.

Comment: Strangely, this code did seem to run quite a bit slower than splitting the code, but only a few milliseconds. Not sure why that is but I did go with it because it was shorter and what i was initially going for.

Which is better, I may never know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You either use `pluck` or `select`. And here you can just use `select` and `map`:

```
words = Word.select(:word, :popularity).order(popularity: :desc).limit(100)
@words, @popularity = words.map(&:word), words.map(&:popularity)
```

`pluck` method maps all selected fields in one array while you need separate array for each field.

Comment: That worked!
I think my confusion came from the fact that pluck is an active record method, and I thought it was an array method. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do the map in one line? or is it not worth the complexity?

Comment: Ah, yes, multiple assignment. But not worth it at that point I suppose. Thank you!